# How do I get sorting to work in the DVWP when using custom SQL query to linked server?

Tags: wss-3.0, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, sorting, sql-server

WSS 3.0

I have a non-SQL database linked to a SQL database.  I've created a datasource in SPD using a custom query to this database.

```
select * from LINKEDDB...sometable
```

I then created a data view web part from this data source, which seems to work just fine.

However, sorting doesn't seem to work.  Nothing happens.  When I use the OPENQUERY syntax for the custom SQL statement, sorting breaks the web part.

I have a vague notion of why it's not working.  Is there something I can do using parameters in my query to enable sorting?  (actually, I would assume that sorting happens via xslt, so I'm not sure at all why it's not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done with with Non-SQL databases but I do know that the sorting and filtering options have to be done using a view.  I am not very experienced with the DVWP but that is what I have found out through google searches and trial/error.

Comment: I would give you an upvote but I don't have the rep.  Indeed, creating a view solved the problem.  Thanks!